# Running Landscape server on CentOS/RHEL?

Tags: landscape

We have a few workstations here running 16.04 LTS, but our only server is on CentOS. Is it reasonably possible to setup Canonical's [Landscape](https://landscape.canonical.com/) on CentOS/RHEL?

Comment: Close voters: Landscape is an ubuntu product so asking if it can run on another operating system would not appear to be off-topic to me.

Comment: I added a link (and a reference to Canonical) to hopefully make this slightly more clear.

Comment: Landscape is on topic, however, you may get a better and quicker answer at http://unix.stackexchange.com/ just because they are likely to have users who have face the same issue. As cent OS is based on Red hat and not Ubuntu, you may be out of luck, I would mail the CentOS devs too, they may have a solution  already https://wiki.centos.org/GettingHelp/ListInfo.

Comment: And what is wrong with Red Hat Satellite (or Spacewalk as the open source version is called http://spacewalk.redhat.com/ )

Answer (score 0):

The server package can be downloaded free of charge -- but is distributed only as a binary .deb installable under Ubuntu and is under a proprietary license.  It's mostly all python, thus the source is visible and you can attempt to install it anywhere.  That said, I would recommend against trying to install directly on RHEL, sounds painful.

For a small installation, have you considered just a VM?  Landscape server should run fine in there and would give you a better idea of how things function.